# Lumia 930 not showing up in explorer

Tags: 8.1, windows-8, usb

I'm dealing with a big problem regarding to the connection between my Windows 8.1 Pro N (x64) operating system and my new Windows Phone "Nokia Lumia 930".

What I want to do is to access data (music, pictures etc.) on my phone through the explorer, but every time I plug in the (original) micro-usb cable to my computer my phone doesn't show up under "computer".

*Note: I have all latest updates for my phone as well as my operating system. There was no need updating the wp8.1 os because it was already up-to-date!*

After taking a quick look under the device manager i noticed that my phone is mentioned under "other devices" together with an exclamation-mark (error code 28). So the driver is missing, but isn't this a plug&play device?

What I tried so far:

1. re-plugin the phone to the computers usb port multiple times
2. using different usb ports of my computer
3. using another micro-usb cable

Any ideas?

Comment: while the phone is connected via USB, have you tried uninstall/removing the phone from Device Manager then re-detecting it?

Comment: of course i did, but same error!

Comment: Removing my phone from device manager then restarting it and plugging it in again fixed this for me.

Comment: nope, not for me. i also tried using the windows phone desktop app but i can't even use it because it's minimizing itself all the time it gets focus! very strange

Comment: that is odd, the app should not do that. It should open and wait until a phone is connected. Antivirus/spyware scan?

Comment: i'm using avast and haven't had any problems with viruses/spyware so far. my system is 100% clean and secured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I'm using MS Windows 8.1 Pro N (OS) so I just installed the "Media Feature Pack" for the N/KN-Edition... now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

go to the device manager and update the drivers from the internet with this symbol (?)
i am do this and my lumia 930 connected and showed on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this solution from (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpnetwork/nokia-lumia-930-and-630-with-windows-phone-81-wont/f51ebc72-fe0f-42ec-ba75-e468c3fb763f)

As an alternative, can you try installing Windows Phone app (http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009). Also the app should have been automatically been downloaded, but not sure why it doesn't.

This app has the following features:

Features:

- Get your music, photos, and videos from your computer to your phone
  (and vice versa).
- Add ringtones and playlists to your phone.
- Quickly share things from your phone with Windows 8 apps (like
  Photos, or Search). You don’t even have to open the Windows Phone app
  to move things around.
- Automatically save photos and videos you take with your phone to
  your PC.
- See at a glance how much space you’re using for each type of
  content, so it’s easy to make sure you never run out of room on your 
  phone.
- Get to WindowsPhone.com to download apps, learn more about your
  phone, or find it if it’s lost.

Comment: as already mentioned above the windows phone app is minimizing itself if it gets focus, so i can't use it!

Comment: @neuronal.bit - Could you try the solution in my first link - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpnetwork/nokia-lumia-930-and-630-with-windows-phone-81-wont/f51ebc72-fe0f-42ec-ba75-e468c3fb763f

Comment: i already tried the solution with changing the driver to "winusb device" but the phone isn't showing up in my explorer!

Comment: Did you try specifically the last one? Your suggestion worked, but a "twist" had to be made first :-)

Uninstall all drivers and delete the media. Unpluck your phone, turn it of. DO NOT turn it on, but pluck it back into your computer. HERE COMES the new stuff that worked for me.

**  Be fast to click the popup window with the installation will start to install, and stop the installation **

Comment: Yes, first of I've ejected the phone from my pc and uninstalled all usb drivers. From that point on my mouse quit its work and I had to reboot the system, but on startup no message, regarding to usb driver installation, appeared. All drivers have been installed again.